# Can using a dictionary on standard letters work in the same or similar way using a text file?

Tags: python, dictionary, import

The following code shows how the standard alphabet can be translated using a dictionary.

```
letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
encryption_code = 'LFWOAYUISVKMNXPBDCRJTQEGHZ'
randomlist  = "Hello world!"
letters += letters.lower()
encryption_code += encryption_code.lower()
enc = dict(zip(letters,encryption_code))
display_enc = "".join([enc.get(ch, ch) for ch in randomlist])
print(display_enc)
```

I was wondering if there was a way to apply this method and get the individual characters of a text file and encrypt it in the same or similar way. This is what I've tried:

```
letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
encryption_code = 'LFWOAYUISVKMNXPBDCRJTQEGHZ'
letters += letters.lower()
encryption_code += encryption_code.lower()
enc = dict(zip(letters,encryption_code))

file_name = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text files","*.txt")])

import_list = []

with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    import_list = f.readlines()

display_enc2 = "".join([enc.get(ch, ch) for ch in import_list])
print(display_enc2)
```

But this doesn't encrypt the letters in the file you choose to import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by making use of the [translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and [maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) methods in `str`

Here is an example of translating a string using `translate` and `maketrans`:

```
print("This Is Now TrAnsLateD".upper().translate(str.maketrans("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "LFWOAYUISVKMNXPBDCRJTQEGHZ")))
JISR SR XPE JCLXRMLJAO
```

So, when using `readlines`, you will get a list of strings probably something like this:

```
list_of_words = ["words and words\n", "I like words\n", "Me too\n"]
```

So, similarly to what you did, you can do this (accounting for removing `\n` as specified in comments):

```
translated = [i.upper().strip().translate(str.maketrans("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "LFWOAYUISVKMNXPBDCRJTQEGHZ")) for i in list_of_words]
```

Output:

```
['EPCOR LXO EPCOR', 'S MSKA EPCOR', 'NA JPP']
```

Comment: So how would I make it not print the `/n'`?

Comment: call `.strip()` on the string.

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to a) Print it on a new line if the file has it on a new line? b)Remove commas and square brackets?

Comment: If you want newlines you should not have removed the '\n'. '\n' is the newline character. So don't use `strip()` that way it preserves the newlines. If you are looking to remove characters like punctuation from the string you should look in to `replace` or even better regex to remove punctuation in the string.